# Best practice with a schedule/queue service?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, queue

I am currently working on a project, this project is basically a web site which as its main function, runs a long calculation task (this task is made up of between 1-10 sub tasks) - (takes about 30-40 seconds to complete on average) and returns a result to the user, as it stands the code uses multiple threading in the site itself (which i don't really like the idea of), so the site continues to run after a button click, whilst this thread in the background continues the calculation.

I'd ideally like to move this calculation into a separate service, to stop the issues related to running threading in a web app. My idea is that it should be a separate service that runs every X seconds to see if any jobs are present in the database, if there are, run them, but i have little experience in writing a reoccurring windows service, and was wondering if anyone has any ideas on the matter, is this the right way to go about such a task, does anyone have any experience of doing something similar, and can anybody recommend any particular ways I should proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a similar project. I was thinking about create a service, like you, but I didn't see the benefits in my case. I have to do some long calculations, and put it in the cache. I don't know if this is the best practice but what I did was to create a timer on global.asax, perform my calculations and put it into cache. When the request comes I give the last cached value.

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

In a situation like this I always prefer to create a tcp listener that accepts the requests from the clients. If I am using .net, my first choice would be wcf service with tcp or named pipe binding. Then when I receive a request, I start a thread to proceed the request. When the long running process finally ends, I return a callback to the client, which was a url that specified in the first request to the scheduler. IMHO this is the best way to do it.

However you may want to build your application on a proven framework like NServiceBus, RhinoBus, etc. You may implement the same business over them too.